# Role based redirecting

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redirect, router

I want to redirect user depending on his role. F.e. When user entered as 'Teacher', he is redirected on page '1'; if he entered as 'Student', he is redirected on page '2'. It has also to work when user inputs only main url 'app.com' (F.e.)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TesLandingPageContainer,
    canActivate: [AutheticatedGuard],
    canActivateChild: [UserRoleGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/users/profile',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
  ...
  },          
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];
```

I have this guard

```
@Injectable()
export class AutheticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(getIsAuthenticated),
      filter(isAuth => isAuth != null),
      tap(isAuth => {
        if (!isAuth) {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  }
}
```

If I write so, it loops

````
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(getUserRoleAndAuth),
      filter(user => user.isAuth != null),
      tap(user => {
        switch (user.role) {
          case 'ADMIN': {
            this.router.navigate(['user/requests']);
            break;
          }
          case 'TEACHER': {
            this.router.navigate(['groups']);
            break;
          }
          case 'STUDENT': {
            this.router.navigate(['student']);
            break;
          }
          default: {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
        }
      }),
      map(user => user.isAuth),
      take(1)
    );
    ```
````

Comment: You are going in the right direction. You have to use a Guard for it. You can write that logic in your `AuthenticatedGuard`. Inject `Router` as a dependency in there and then navigate the user to a particular route based on the user type.

Comment: Do you get the role of the logged in user in your `AuthGuard`? If not, you'll need to find a way to get that role in order to navigate the user to an appropriate route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `this.router.navigate(['student']);` use `return this.router.parseUrl('/student');`

`parseUrl` will create `UrlTree` which help to navigate application from `CanActivate`.

you need to return somthing from `CanActivate` interface , either boolean or UrlTree.

As per your logic return either student or teacher URL.

Comment: and how can I to redirect on default pages only when user inputted incorrect address or wrote only  'app.com'?